# How to centre an image in an equation?

Tags: graphics, vertical-alignment

I have a [tiny image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BRkhs.png):

[image: tiny image]

I want to insert it into a simple equation.

### What I want:

> [image]

### My failed attempt:

```
$$\includegraphics[scale=.4,halign=c]{tiny_image.png}} \equiv x$$
```

[image]

### Question

How can I make the bottom of the image drop below the equation?
How do I centre the image so that it looks like the image in "**What I want**"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The "normal" way would be to use the `\vcenter` primitive. However, the snippet you provided uses `halign` as option to `\includegraphics`, which suggests that you are using the `adjustbox` package; in this case you can use the `valign` key. Here an example with both ways.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}

\begin{document}

\[
a + \includegraphics[width=3em,valign=c]{example-image}
  + \vcenter{\hbox{\includegraphics[width=3em]{example-image}}} = c
\]
```

[image]

Unrelated: please have a look at [Why is `\[ … \]` preferable to `$$ … $$`?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/503/82917)